# IntelliSenseMode: gcc-x64 vs clang-x64?

Tags: c++, ide, intellisense, visual-studio-code

According to [the documentation of vscode for c++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp), the  ***intelliSenseMode*** has two different modes:

- ***gcc-x64***
- ***clang-x64***

I just wonder:

**What are the differences between the two modes?**

Comment: From the link - _"...The most common reason for this is missing __include paths and defines__. The easiest way to fix this on each platform is as follows:...Set __intelliSenseMode__ ..."_

Answer (score 0):

This option tells intelliSense which compiler to use. So either `gcc` or `clang`.
From the official docs of VS Code ([here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties)):

> *intelliSenseMode*: The IntelliSense mode to use that maps to an architecture-specific variant of MSVC, gcc, or Clang. If not set or if set to *${default}*, the extension will choose the default for that platform.
>
> Platform defaults:
>
> - Windows: *msvc-x64*
> - Linux: *gcc-x64*
> - macOS: *clang-x64*

For a comparison between the two compilers, see e.g. [here](https://alibabatech.medium.com/gcc-vs-clang-llvm-an-in-depth-comparison-of-c-c-compilers-899ede2be378).